# Thread Dump: What to look for to determine the thread responsible for 100% CPU?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-dump

Attempting to troubleshoot a 100% CPU consumption on a large system running hundreds of threads concurrently, I generated a thread dump with the help of this Oracle's [Diagnosing a Looping Process](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-VM/html/hangloop.html) article.

To  find **which** thread is responsible for this high CPU consumption, I know that I should focus on on the threads that are in the `RUNNABLE` state, but there are **dozens** of them. So it is like finding a needle in a haystack.

What else should I be looking for among all those threads in the `RUNNABLE` state, to focus on the particular thread that is responsible for the 100% CPU consumption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On linux:
1. You can get the busiest thread id by command: `top -Hp $(pidof java)`
2. And then convert the thread id to hexadecimal: `prinrf "%x\n" {the tid}`
3. Now, search the hexadecimal id in the thread-dump, That is the thread that consumes the most CPU.

On other operation systems, google How to find the busiest thread in a process.

Answer (score 2):

The Windows side of @meng's excellent answer:

1. Run Microsoft's [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) and take a screenshot of it while:
2. Take a thread dump by Ctrl+Break at the Java process console.
3. Spot the top CPU consuming TIDs in the 'Threads' tab of the process properties (in Process Explorer) and convert those numbers to Hex.
4. Locate those hex numbers in the thread dump (appear as 'nid' == native id).